# JQuery and ACE-Editor not playing well together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I am building some modules to teach intro coding concepts to some of my students
http://jsbin.com/pacaxoza/3/edit

When a user writes their own function, I want the editor which is highlighting each line as it goes to jump to the function when it is called so the user can see that their function is read when they call it. All of this is in the jsbin above (the canvas with animation based on the code is not in the jsbin for clarity reasons).

In Javascript mode Ace Editor surrounds any user defined functions in a span with class'ace_function'. I could not find an easy way to find and store values from user created functions in ace methods so instead I am using JQuery to find each span with the class 'ace_function'. I am using JQuery index to find what lines those functions are on, and then passing that info to ace methods to render.

The issue is if the editor is scrolled to the top, everything works fine, but if you scroll down any in the editor and hit submit, the editor's indexing seems to be off by a couple lines of code and everything breaks down.

Does anyone have suggestions for a better way to approach this problem, or what could be causing the erratic behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ace uses virtual viewport and creates dom elements only for visible lines, so using jquery won't work.
You need to use Ace api instead, `session.getLine(number)->string`, `session.getTokens(number)->[{type, value}, ...]`.
tokenIterator might be useful as well see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/edit_session/bracket_match.js#L34 for an example

Comment: Okay, so I need to find each user defined function, get its name, starting line, and ending line. If I just search for the word function ace api does not return the line number of the search results. There is no method to find tokens that are user defined functions. What is the best way to find and get the information from functions the user has created?

Comment: As I've said, use token iterator. See http://jsbin.com/pacaxoza/5/edit where i modified click handler, getCode needs to be changed in a similar way.